# Сохраняется ли время модификации файлов в Mercurial и Bazaar (в отличии от Git)?

Tags: git, контроль-версий, mercurial, bazaar

Попробовал Git и с удивлением обнаружил, что при `checkout` (в том числе **при переключении веток (!!!)**) время модификации файлов (это то, что показывает `ls -l`) меняется на текущее.

Далее я вычитал в [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Why_isn.27t_Git_preserving_modification_time_on_files.3F), что так и было задумано, но мне такое поведение решительно не понравилось.

В связи с чем и возник данный вопрос --
а как с аналогичными вещами обстоит дело в других, вроде бы (по описаниям в сети), во многом похожих VCS -- Mercurial и Bazaar?

Comment: 1. Вроде бы с git 2.2.2 он больше не меняет время для up-to-date файлов

Comment: 2. не знаю
3. Я работал со всеми тремя, из них под линуксом с гитом и меркуриалом. Для моего лично воркфлоу принципиальных отличий нет, возможно потому что я здоров привык к мелким недостаткам гита. При работе с другими разработчиками гит выигрывает исключительно за счет распространенности: легче гуглятся ответы и  прикручиваются всякие сторонние штуки.

Comment: @ru_volt, спасибо, но к сожалению: `cat /etc/issue; git --version 
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS \n \l

git version 2.7.4` меняет (только что пробовал `git co master; git co style`).

Comment: А зачем вам время модификации файлов? У них простите целая история есть, что вам ещё надо?

Comment: @Monk, а мне так более привычно (к тому же я крайне не люблю, когда кто-то (Линус?) неожиданно навязывет свою т.з.)

Comment: @avp, странно, вроде бы они это поведение меняли, приду домой посмотрю под линуксом. Под виндой 2.8.1 никакая дата не меняется

Comment: @avp - не нравится поведение git (или любой другой системы контроля версий) - форкните и добавьте свой функционал. Делов то. А можно и свою систему написать, с датами и програмистками.

Comment: @avp, я просто не совсем уверен - а какой должна быть дата изменения файлов, которые я запулил? По идее - таки дата пула, именно тогда файлы на диске поменялись.

Comment: @Monk, imho очевидно. Время модификации файла на момент `commit`.

Comment: @KoVadim, да и в самом деле делов-то. Добавить файл в который класть SHA1 вметсте со временем создания этого блоба и вынимать оттуда это время при checkout. Только нафига мне одному лишь самому себе это делать (формат-то получается не совместимый)?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что если хранить - то только время изменения? Давайте тогда хранить ещё кучу метаинформации файла - заодно права, чтобы вы не могли открыть файл после пула, ведь никто не выдавал вам права на файл. Вы хотите херни в файловом понимании.

Comment: @Monk, rebase в любом случае копирует данные в файлы из нужных блобов. Просто с каждым  надо связать время модификации файла из которого его делали. Идею реализации только что написал в комментарии для KoVadim.

Comment: @Monk, я не собираюсь спорить тут о том, что нужно, а что нет из метаданных.

Comment: Добавьте сюда часовые пояса и некорректные настройки у тех, кто коммитит. Я не хочу файлы из будущего.

Comment: *с удивлением обнаружил* — да, файловые системы — они такие, очень удивительные. ещё и разные бывают. большинство из тех, с которыми я знаком, вообще три разных времени сохраняют для одного (!) файла: [время последнего чтения содержимого, время последнего измнения содержимого и время изменения метаинформации (права, имя)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2803/110559). // *навязывет свою т.з.* — ну, что поделать, такие вот они нехорошие, те, кто придумал сохранять время **последней** модификации содержимого файла (именно его показывает упоминаемая `ls -l`).

Comment: Ну так по вашей же ссылке на faq приведён бронебойный аргумент. Он по определению перевешивает вашу вкусовщину и применим к любой системе контроля версий

Comment: @AlexeyTen, тем не менее половина из [упомянутых в вике CVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software#Advanced_features) сохраняет время модификации. Думаю, что ключик типа --mtime (или --touch :-)) в `git checkout` мог бы "примерить мнения сторон..."

Comment: Никому не нужно. Можете написать сами, это несложно. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2458146

Comment: @AlexeyTen, как это можно делать и почему я не буду этим заниматься я уже написал выше (в комментарии для KoVadim)  / А никому не нужно -- это дело привычки и взглядов на разработку (поверьте, тут ооочень много разных мнений).

Comment: Никому из тех кто использует гит это не нужно настолько, что бы сесть и сделать. В том числе вам. В общем, на мой взгляд вопрос исчерпан.

Answer (score 3):

GIT - система хранения версий. Не файлов в какой то файловой системе.

В плане гита два файла с одинаковым содержимым - одинаковы. У них совпадает хеш и всё хорошо.

В файловой системе изменение текстового файла с условного текста "1" на "2" а потом обратно - это модификация файла, дважды. В гите - файл остался без изменений, пушить нечего.

Ещё веселее - я открыл проект, написал изменений, даже не коммитил ничего - файлы изменены. Отмена изменений средствами гита теперь должна и время изменения файлов откатывать?
Та же ситуация, некоторые файлы я откатил средствами IDE - просто зажал Ctrl+Z. Гит их пушить сейчас не предлагает, ваш гит - предложит. Вы историей в гите пользовались? Она и так обычно с кучей коммитов на каждый файл, вы эту цифру увеличите в несколько раз.

В целом - скорее всего вы хотите получить что-то не то. Возможно, стоит сформулировать вопрос иначе, чтобы пояснить, чем вам мешает текущая реализация?

Comment: А Вы на какую часть вопроса отвечаете?

Comment: @avp, я пытаюсь объяснить логичность текущего поведение и нелогичность обратного поведения. Автор не захотел объяснить, зачем ему это, поэтому написал в общих целях.

Comment: Прямо скажем, текущее поведение (см. [FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Why_isn.27t_Git_preserving_modification_time_on_files.3F)) логично с т.з. "верховного компоновщика" (Линуса?), но абсолютно не логично с т.з. разработчика, "прыгающего" по веткам. Наверное с этим согласны и авторы доброй половины [других CVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software#Advanced_features), которые хранят дату модификации файлов (а не только коммита).

Comment: @avp, git\tfs\svn\mercurial - не поддерживают. Серьезно, основные системы, которыми сейчас пользуются не поддерживают этой фигни. Не потому что они злые мудаки, а потому что это никому нахер не надо.

Comment: Дипломатично выражаясь об обозначенных персонах, заявим, что стороны остались при своем мнении.

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению (в данном случае я спрашивал серьезно, не зная заранее ответа), все же, "гугл рулит".

Вот [тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software), в разделе [Advanced features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version_control_software#Advanced_features) можно увидеть, что **все 3 системы не поддерживают искомую фичу** -- `timestamp preservation: Overwrites the last modified filesystem attribute with the commit time upon checkout.`

Правда, там же, для Mercurial есть ссылка на [Timestamp Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TimestampExtension) (следует заметить --   `is not distributed with Mercurial`).

Могу предположить, что аналогичные расширения существуют и для 2-х других.